# How to toggle off an element when another element is activated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two elements. 
if 1 is already toggled on, then when I toggle on 2, 1 should toggle off.
I am still new to javascript, so if someone wuold help please thanks. Right now, when I try to click, nothing happens, if I remove the while loop, then it works. Maybe I have some error in there that I am unsure off, but it looks right base on the logic.

```
<style>
.mystyle {
width: 300px;
height: 50px;
background-color: coral;
color: white;
font-size: 25px;
}

.newClassName {
width: 400px;
height: 100px;
background-color: lightblue;
text-align: center;
font-size: 25px;
color: navy;
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Click the button to toggle between two classes.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Try it 2</button>

<div id="myDIV" class="mystyle">
I am a DIV element
</div>

<div id="myDIV2" class="mystyle">
I am a DIV element2
</div>
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var y = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
function myFunction() {
x.classList.toggle("newClassName");
}
function myFunction2() {
y.classList.toggle("newClassName");
}
while (x.classList.contains("newClassName")) {
if (y.classList.contains("newClassName") = true) {
     x.classList.toggle("newClassName")；
}
}

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may reduce all to only one function because, from MDN:

> toggle ( String [, force] )
>   When only one argument is present: Toggle class value; i.e., if class exists then remove it and return false, if not, then add it and return true.
>   When a second argument is present: If the second argument is true, add specified class value, and if it is false, remove it.

So the code is:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var y = document.getElementById("myDIV2");
function myFunction() {
  var result = x.classList.toggle("newClassName");
  y.classList.toggle("newClassName", !result);
}
```

```css
.mystyle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.newClassName {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: navy;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to toggle between two classes.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it 2</button>

<div id="myDIV" class="mystyle">
    I am a DIV element
</div>

<div id="myDIV2" class="mystyle">
    I am a DIV element2
</div>
```

Comment: Then you should place `newClassName` to at least one element by default. ;) But then it doesn't fully match the behavior in the original question ...

Answer (score 3):

You mixed up plain JavaScript and jQuery. I rewrote the script. I think this is what you wanted ...

```js
var x = $("#myDIV");
var y = $("#myDIV2");

function myFunction() {
    x.toggleClass("newClassName");
  
    if( x.hasClass("newClassName") ) {
        y.removeClass("newClassName");
    }
}

function myFunction2() {
    y.toggleClass("newClassName");
  
    if( y.hasClass("newClassName") ) {
        x.removeClass("newClassName");
    }
}
```

```css
.mystyle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: coral;
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.newClassName {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: navy;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Click the button to toggle between two classes.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<button onclick="myFunction2()">Try it 2</button>

<div id="myDIV" class="mystyle">
  I am a DIV element
</div>

<div id="myDIV2" class="mystyle">
  I am a DIV element2
</div>
```

Comment: You beat me to it :P

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `while loop`

You mixed plain JS with jQuery. 
the code is commented
[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alexisdiamondhotmailca/oesabneo/1/)

### EDIT

As pointed out in the comment, my answer should include code so here it is:

**Javascript**

```
$(function() { // This part was proposed by eisbehr
var div1 = $('#myDIV');
var div2 = $('#myDIV2');

$('#btn1').click(function() {
    div1.toggleClass('newClassName');

    if (div2.hasClass('newClassName')) {
        div2.removeClass('newClassName');
    }
});

$('#btn2').click(function() {
    div2.toggleClass('newClassName');

    if (div1.hasClass('newClassName')) {
        div1.removeClass('newClassName');
    }
});
```

});

**HTML**

```
<p>Click the button to toggle between two classes.</p>
<button id="btn1">Try it</button>
<button id="btn2">Try it 2</button>

<div id="myDIV" class="mystyle">
  I am a DIV element
</div>

<div id="myDIV2" class="mystyle">
  I am a DIV element2
</div>
```

Comment: You should post the code here and not only a link, so everybody could see what you did. And beside that, when not using the OPs code, you should do it in the beste possible way. Your example had different issues and design problems. Maybe compare this to yours: https://jsfiddle.net/oesabneo/2/ But your Ideas was good! ;)

Comment: @eisbehr i wasn't able to make `function()` work. thanks!

Comment: @eisbehr How do you publish snippet (I don't know, that why i made a jsFiddle)